# Unable to change a 'str' into an 'int', can only use float

Tags: python, web-scraping, integer

I have the below code. This snippet:

```
pe = df[3][0]
pe = int(pe)
print(pe)
```

Does not work and will return the error in the 'exception' part of the code below:

```
ticker = input("Please choose a ticker symbol: ")
print("Loading data for " + ticker.upper())
    
try:
    #Pulling the data for the chosen ticker.
    url = ('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker.upper())
    req = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"})
    df = table[0]
    
    #Pulls company name.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for title in soup.find_all('title'):
        print(title.get_text())
    
    pe = df[3][0]
    pe = int(pe)
    print(pe)
    
    #Ratios and metrics to be checked.
    data = {
        df[10][10]: ["$" + df[11][10]], #Stock Price
        df[2][0]: [df[3][0]], #P/E
        df[2][1]: [df[3][1]], #Forward P/E
        df[2][2]: [df[3][2]], #PEG
        df[2][3]: [df[3][3]], #P/S
        df[2][6]: [df[3][6]], #P/FCF
        df[0][7]: [df[1][7]], #Dividend %
        df[6][5]: [df[7][5]]  #ROE
    }
    
    #Framing the table and printing the results.
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ["Stats:"])
    print(df)
    
except ValueError:
    print("Ticker doesn't exist. Please check your selection.")
```

This returns:

```
Loading data for KO
KO The Coca-Cola Company Stock Quote
Ticker doesn't exist. Please check your selection.
```

When I use this:

```
pe = int(float(pe))
```

It works but it rounds it to 30 for Coca-Cola for example. I'd like to return the exact number but turning it into an int isn't as straightforward as it seems. I did use type() to make sure the original piece of data is a str and df[3][0] is a str.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How do you exactly want to convert a float to an integer, can you give an example? Do you want to implement some kind of rounding?

Comment: ```float('30.42')``` gives ```30.42``` and ```int(float('30.42'))``` gives 30. What value do you wish to get ?

Comment: If you would remove the try except you probably would get the error exactly saying what is wrong and what can't be converted. While converting strings to floats there often can be problems, if the string is somehow misformatted.

Comment: @Ram - thank you for that... man, I feel stupid. I didn't think to just use float, I thought I can only work with numbers if they were integers.